# Toggle options in select field? show content inside select field after choosing an option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I add Toggle options with content inside select field?

show content inside select field after choosing an option as shown in the image
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d9VCx.jpg)

you can see working example after clicking 'book now' > special offers > rommance in menu on http://www.111resorts.com

Here is my html

```js
var _slideshow_current    = 0;
var _slideshow_next       = 0;
var _slideshow_maximal    = 0;
var _slideshow_width      = 0;
var _slideshow_autorun    = true;
var _front_slide_maximal  = 0;

(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var height_screen = $(window).height();
        $('.views_slideshow_cycle_main .image-field-caption').each(function(poc) {
          var str = $(this).html();
          if (parseInt(str.indexOf("<br"))>0) {
            $(this).addClass('two_line');
          }
          $(this).css({'top':parseInt(height_screen/2)+'px'});
        });
        $('#custom-helpers-reservation-so1-form .form-item-eZ-Nights input').change(function(poc) {
          var prem_code = $(this).siblings('label').find('.prem_code').html();
          $(this).closest('#custom-helpers-reservation-so1-form').find('.field-offer-promocode').val(prem_code); 
        });
        $('#block-custom-helpers-custom-helpers-book-now h2').click(function() {
          $(this).parent().toggleClass('form_shown');
        });
        if ($('body').hasClass('page-bali') || $('body').hasClass('page-lombok')) {
          $('#block-custom-helpers-custom-helpers-book-now').toggleClass('form_shown');
        }  
        $('.procode_select_content .main_select').click(function() {
          $('.procode_select_content .main_select_content').slideToggle(300,function() {
            $('.procode_select_content .main_subselect_content').hide();
          });
          $('.special_reservation_form .field-promocode').val('');
          $('.procode_select_content .procode_option').removeClass('selected');
        });
        $('.procode_select_content .main_subselect').click(function() {
          var parent  = $(this).parent();
          var nights  = $(this).attr('rel').split(',');
          var is_open = parent.hasClass('selected');
          $('#edit-ez-nights option').removeAttr('disabled');
        
          $('.procode_select_content .procode_option').removeClass('selected');
          $('.special_reservation_form .field-promocode').val('');
          $('.procode_select_content .main_subselect_content:visible').slideUp();
          if (!is_open) {
            parent.find('.main_subselect_content').slideDown();
            $('.special_reservation_form .field-promocode').val(parent.attr('rel'));
            parent.addClass('selected');
            if (nights) {
              var selected = false;
              $('#edit-ez-nights option').attr('disabled','disabled');
              for (var prop in nights) {
                $('#edit-ez-nights option[value="'+nights[prop]+'"]').removeAttr('disabled');
                if (!selected) {
                  $('#edit-ez-nights').val(nights[prop]); 
                  selected = true; 
                }
              }
            }
          }
        });
        $('.view-front-page .views-row').supersize();
        _front_slide_maximal = ($('.view-front-page .views-row').length-1);
    
        $('table.dowload_table .form-type-password input, .special_reservation_form .form-item-promotioncode input').focus( function() {
            $(this).parents('.form-item').find('label').hide();
        });
        $('table.dowload_table .form-type-password input, .special_reservation_form .form-item-promotioncode input').blur( function() {
            if ($(this).val()=='') {
                $(this).parents('.form-item').find('label').show();  
            };
        });
        $('.scroll_top').click(function() {
          $('html, body, .mobile_content_wrap_inner').animate({
              scrollTop: 0
          }, 500);  
        });
        
        if ($('input#edit-promotioncode').val()!='') {
            $('.form-item-promotioncode label').hide();
        }            
        $('.webform-client-form .form-submit').click(function() {
          $('.webform-component--left-container--code input').val('4444');      
        });
        $('.field-name-field-link-name .field-item, .close_btn').click(function() {
          $('.field-name-field-subtexts, .close_btn_cont').toggle();
          $('html, body, .mobile_content_wrap').animate({
              scrollTop: ($(".field-name-field-link-name").offset().top-80)
          }, 500);
        });
        _slideshow_maximal = ($('.second_content_content .single_content').length-1);
        if (_slideshow_maximal>0) {
          _slideshow_width = $('.slide_content_wrapper').width();
          var new_node = $('.second_content_content .slide_content .single_content').last().clone();
          $('.second_content_content .slide_content .single_content').first().clone().appendTo('.second_content_content .slide_content');
          new_node.prependTo('.second_content_content .slide_content');
          $('.second_content_content .slide_content').css('left',-_slideshow_width+"px");
          
          $('.second_content_content .right_arrow, .second_content_content .main_right_arrow').click(function() {
            _slideshow_show_next();     
          });
          $('.second_content_content .left_arrow, .second_content_content .main_left_arrow').click(function() {
            _slideshow_next = _slideshow_current-1;
            _start_sliding();      
          });
          $('.slide_pager a').click(function() {
            _slideshow_next = parseInt($(this).attr('rel'));
            _start_sliding();      
          });
          $('.second_content_content').hover(function() {
          },function() {
            _slideshow_autorun = true;     
          });
          $('.second_content_content').click(function() {
            _slideshow_autorun = false;     
          });
          setTimeout(_slideshow_run_func,4000);
        }
        $('.mobile_menu_btn, .mobile_menu h2.top_title').click(function() {
          var main_wrapper = $('.mobile_content_wrap');
          left = parseInt(main_wrapper.css('left').replace('px',''));
          if (left==0) {
            left = -300;
            $("body").addClass('menu_shown');
          }
          else {
            left = 0;
            $("body").removeClass('menu_shown');
          }
          $('.mobile_content_wrap').stop().animate({
            left: left
            },300);     
        });
           
        $('#eZ_child').parent().hide();
    
        $('.special_reservation_form .form-submit').click(function() {
            var date = $('.form-item-eZ-chkin-temp-date input').val().replace(' / ','-').replace(' / ','-').split('-');
            $('.form-item-start-date input').val(date[2]+'-'+date[1]+'-'+date[0]); 
        });
        $("a:regex(href, .*pdf)").attr('target','_blank');
        doLayout();
        $(window).bind('resize', doLayout);
        $('#header .menu-block-wrapper > ul > li > a').click(function() {
          winWidth = $(window).width();
          if (winWidth<=700) {
            if (!$(this).siblings('ul').is(':visible')) {
              $('#header ul.menu li ul:visible').slideUp();  
            }
            $(this).siblings('ul').slideToggle();
            return false;
          }
        });
        
        if ($("body").hasClass('front')) {
          setTimeout(function() {
            $("#header .logo img").fadeIn(3000);
            $("#header .logo span").fadeOut(3000);
          },2000);  
        }
        $('.mobile_content_wrap').scroll(function() {
          if ($('.mobile_content_wrap').scrollTop()>200) {
            $('.scroll_top').show();  
          }
          else {
            $('.scroll_top').hide();
          }  
        });
        $('#block-menu-block-3 .menu-block-wrapper > .menu > li > a').each(function() {
          $(this).html($(this).html()+'<span>&nbsp;</span>'); 
        });
        $('#block-menu-block-3 .menu-block-wrapper > .menu > li > a').click(function() {
          var parent_nore = $(this).parent();
          parent_nore.siblings().removeClass('jsexpanded');
          parent_nore.closest('ul.menu').find('ul.menu').stop().slideUp();
          if (!parent_nore.hasClass('jsexpanded')) {
            parent_nore.addClass('jsexpanded');
            parent_nore.find('ul.menu').stop().slideDown();
          }
          else {
            parent_nore.removeClass('jsexpanded');
          };
          return false; 
        });
        $('#block-menu-block-3--2 .menu-block-wrapper .menu a').each(function() {
          if ($(this).siblings('ul').length>0) {
            $(this).click(function() {
              var parent_nore = $(this).parent();
              if(parent_nore.hasClass('expanded')) {
                parent_nore.removeClass('expanded').addClass('collapsed');
                $(this).siblings('ul.menu').stop().slideUp();
              }
              else {
                parent_nore.removeClass('collapsed').addClass('expanded');
                $(this).siblings('ul.menu').stop().slideDown();
              };
              return false; 
            });
          }
        });
        $('#block-menu-block-3--2 .menu-block-wrapper .menu li').each(function() {
          var ul_children = $(this).children('ul.menu');
          if(ul_children.length>0 && !$(this).hasClass('active-trail')) {
            $(this).removeClass('expanded').addClass('collapsed');
            ul_children.stop().hide();
          }
          else {
            ul_children.stop().show();
          }
        });
    });
   
    $(document).scroll(function() {
      if ($(window).scrollTop()>10) {
        $('.scroll_top').show();  
      }
      else {
        $('.scroll_top').hide();
      }  
    });
         
    function doLayout() {
        var winWidth, headerHeight, footerHeight;
        winWidth = $('#block-system-main').width();
      newH = Math.round(((winWidth/1600)*970));
        $('.juicebox_main_cont').height((newH+40));
     // $('.view-mobile-gallery').height(newH);
    }      
    
    function _slideshow_show_next() {
        _slideshow_next = _slideshow_current+1;
      _start_sliding(); 
    }
    
    var _slideshow_run_func = function _slideshow_run() {
      if (_slideshow_autorun) {
        _slideshow_show_next();   
      }
      setTimeout(_slideshow_run_func,4000);
    }
    
    function _start_sliding() {
      _slideshow_current = _slideshow_next;
      $('.second_content_content .slide_content').stop().animate({left: -((_slideshow_current+1)*_slideshow_width)},500,function() {
        if (_slideshow_next<0) {
          $('.second_content_content .slide_content').css('left',-((_slideshow_maximal+1)*_slideshow_width)+"px");
        }
        else if (_slideshow_next>_slideshow_maximal) {
          $('.second_content_content .slide_content').css('left',-_slideshow_width+"px");
        }
      });
      if (_slideshow_current<0) {
        _slideshow_current = _slideshow_maximal;
      }
      else if (_slideshow_current>_slideshow_maximal) {
        _slideshow_current = 0;
      }
      $('.slide_content_wrapper .slide_pager a').removeClass('active'); 
      $('.slide_content_wrapper .slide_pager a.page_'+_slideshow_current).addClass('active'); 
    }
})(jQuery);

jQuery.expr[':'].regex = function(elem, index, match) {
    var matchParams = match[3].split(','),
    validLabels = /^(data|css):/,
    attr = {
        method: matchParams[0].match(validLabels) ? 
        matchParams[0].split(':')[0] : 'attr',
        property: matchParams.shift().replace(validLabels,'')
    },
    regexFlags = 'ig',
    regex = new RegExp(matchParams.join('').replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,''), regexFlags);
    return regex.test(jQuery(elem)[attr.method](attr.property));
}

function setCookie(c_name,value,expiredays) {
  var exdate=new Date();
  exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate()+expiredays);
  document.cookie=c_name+ "=" +escape(value)+
  ((expiredays==null) ? "" : ";expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
}

function getCookie(c_name) {
  if (document.cookie.length>0)
    {
    c_start=document.cookie.indexOf(c_name + "=");
    if (c_start!=-1)
      {
      c_start=c_start + c_name.length+1;
      c_end=document.cookie.indexOf(";",c_start);
      if (c_end==-1) c_end=document.cookie.length;
      return unescape(document.cookie.substring(c_start,c_end));
      }
    }
  return "";
};
(function($) {
  //Resize image on ready or resize
  $.fn.supersize = function() {  
    //Invoke the resizenow() function on document ready
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.view-front-page .views-row').resizenow();
        //$('#maincontent-wrapper').setrightheight();
    });
    //Invoke the resizenow() function on browser resize
    $(window).bind("resize", function() {
        $('.view-front-page .views-row').resizenow();
        //$('#maincontent-wrapper').setrightheight();
    });
  };                                                                                     
  //Adjust image size
  $.fn.resizenow = function() {
    //Define starting width and height values for the original image
    $(this).width($(".view-front-page").width());
    $(this).find('img').each(function(poc) {
      startwidth = $(this).attr('width');  
      startheight = $(this).attr('height');
    
      //Define image ratio
      ratio = startheight/startwidth;
      //Gather browser dimensions
      browserwidth = $('body').width();
      browserheight = $(window).height();
      
      //Resize image to proper ratio
      if ((browserheight/browserwidth) > ratio) {
          $(this).height(browserheight);
          $(this).width((browserheight / ratio));
          //$(this).find('img').height(browserheight);
          //$(this).find('img').width(browserheight / ratio);
      } else {
          newheight = (browserwidth * ratio);
          //console.debug(newheight);
          $(this).css('width',browserwidth);
          $(this).css('height',newheight);
          //console.debug(browserwidth+" - "+ ratio);
          //$(this).find('img').width(browserwidth);
          //$(this).find('img').height(browserwidth * ratio);
      }
      //console.debug("----------------------");
      //Make sure the image stays center in the window
      $(this).css('left', (browserwidth - $(this).width())/2);
      $(this).css('top', (browserheight - $(this).height())/2);
    });
  };
  //Adjust image size
  $.fn.setrightheight = function() {
    var browserheight = $(window).height();
    $(this).css({"height":(browserheight-160)+"px"});
  };
})(jQuery);;
```

```css
.special_reservation_form .container-inline-date .form-item input[type="text"] {
    background: #fff url(icon_calendar.png?v=1) no-repeat right center;
    width: 92px;}
input[type="text"], input[type="password"], input[type="email"], select {
    border: 1px solid #a29c8b;
    background: #fff;
    width: 200px;
    height: 18px;
    line-height: 18px;
    font-size: 11px;
    padding: 2px 8px;
    font-family: "ZurichBT-RomanCondensed";
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}






.page-special-offers #block-system-main,.node-webform{text-align:center;}
.special_offer_form{text-transform:uppercase;margin-bottom:40px;}
.special_offer_form .form-radio{display:none;}
.special_offer_form h2{margin:0 0 30px 0;}
.special_offer_form .column_content{text-align:left;height:320px;}
.special_offer_form.imported_offer .column_content{height:auto;margin-bottom:20px;}
.special_offer_form.imported_offer h2{margin:0 0 20px 0;}
.special_offer_form .more_desc,.special_offer_form ul,.special_offer_form p{text-transform:none;}
.special_offer_form .form-type-radio{padding:8px 0;border-top:1px solid #a29c8b;border-bottom:1px solid #a29c8b;margin:0 0 -1px 0;}

.special_offer_form .form-type-radio:after,.node-webform:after{clear:both;content:".";display:block;height:0;visibility:hidden;}
.special_offer_form .form-type-radio input,.special_offer_form .form-type-radio label{float:left;}
.special_offer_form .form-type-radio input{margin:5px 10px 0 0;}
.special_offer_form .form-type-radio label{width:272px;}
.special_offer_form .more_desc,.form_more_info ul,.form_more_info p{display:inline-block;font-size:11px;line-height:14px;}
.form_more_info ul,.form_more_info p{margin:0px;}
.form_more_info ul{margin-bottom:16px;}
.form_more_info ul,.form_more_info li{list-style:none;padding:0px;margin:0px;}
.form_more_info li{padding-left:20px;position:relative;}
.form_more_info .header{margin-top:20px;}



input[type="text"],input[type="password"],input[type="email"],select{border:1px solid #a29c8b;background:#fff;width:200px;height:18px;line-height:18px;font-size:11px;padding:2px 8px;font-family:"ZurichBT-RomanCondensed";letter-spacing:1px;}::-webkit-input-placeholder{font-size:12px;}:-moz-placeholder{font-size:12px;}::-moz-placeholder{font-size:12px;}:-ms-input-placeholder{font-size:12px;}

select{padding:4px;height:24px;width:80px;}

form label{line-height:24px;}.webform-client-form{position:relative;}


.form_shown .special_reservation_form{display:block;}
.special_reservation_form .form-item{margin:0 0 8px 0;}
.special_reservation_form .form-item label{float:left;width:66px;font-weight:normal;font-size:12px;}
.special_reservation_form .form-item .form-item{margin:0;}
.special_reservation_form .form-type-date-popup .date-padding label,.special_reservation_form .form-type-date-popup .description{display:none;}
.special_reservation_form .form-type-date-popup .date-padding{padding:0;}
.special_reservation_form .form-item-promotioncode{position:relative;}
.special_reservation_form .form-submit{background-color:#000;color:#fff;border:1px solid #fff;display:block;margin-top:16px;height:32px;float:right;line-height:32px;font-size:11px;padding:0px 20px;text-align:center;}
.special_reservation_form .form-submit:hover{text-decoration:underline;background-color:#000;}
.special_reservation_form .container-inline-date .form-item input[type="text"]{background:#fff url(icon_calendar.png?v=1) no-repeat right center;width:92px;}
.special_reservation_form .form-item-eZ-chkin-temp,.special_reservation_form .form-item-eZ-room,.special_reservation_form .book_direct{float:left;clear:both;}
.special_reservation_form .form-item-eZ-Nights,.special_reservation_form .form-item-eZ-adult{float:right;}
.special_reservation_form .form-item-eZ-room select,.special_reservation_form .form-item-eZ-Nights select,.special_reservation_form .form-item-eZ-adult select{width:50px;;}
.special_reservation_form .book_direct{line-height:12px;margin-top:10px;font-size:10px}
.special_reservation_form .book_direct a{color:#fff;}
.special_reservation_form .form-item-resort input[type="text"]{width:231px;}
.region-footer,.region-footer div,.region-footer ul,.region-footer li{display:inline;}
.region-footer ul{padding:0px;margin:0px;margin-right:16px;padding-left:0px;}
.region-footer li{border-right:1px solid #A19C84;padding:0px;margin:0px;padding-right:6px;margin-left:6px;float:left;}
.region-footer li.last{border:none;padding:0px;}
.webform-component-date div{display:inline;}
.region-footer{display:block;}
.footer_right_cont{float:right;}
.footer_right_in{float:right;}


.procode_select_content{float:left;width:210px;border:1px solid #a29c8b;background:#fff;color:#000;}
.procode_select_content .main_select_content{display:none;}
.procode_select_content .main_select,.procode_select_content .main_subselect{background:transparent url(http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/cc_mono_icon_set/blacks/16x16/br_down.png) no-repeat right center;padding:2px 8px;line-height:24px;height:24px;cursor:pointer;}
.procode_select_content .main_subselect{background:transparent url(https://nsgi.novascotia.ca/gdd/images/info3.png) no-repeat right center;height:auto;}
.procode_select_content .main_subselect .radio_div{background:none repeat scroll 0 0 #ffffff;border:1px solid #000;content:" "; display:block; height:6px; float:left; margin:8px 8px 0 0;width:6px;border-radius:50%;}
.half_cont{width:80%;margin:0 auto 20px auto;}
.procode_select_content .selected .main_subselect .radio_div{background:#000;}
.procode_select_content .procode_option{border-top:1px solid #a29c8b;}
.procode_select_content .main_subselect_content{font-size:11px;padding:0 8px 6px 8px;line-height:12px;text-transform:none;display:none; color:#000;}
.procode_select_content .main_select, .procode_select_content .main_subselect{ text-align: left; font-size:14px;
    color: #000;}
.procode_select_content .main_subselect {
    text-align: left;
    color: black;
    font-size: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="special_reservation_form clearfix" target="_blank" action="#" method="get" style=" text-align: left; color:#000; font-family:bvilla; max-width: 220px;padding-bottom:10px;" id="custom-helpers-reservation-form" accept-charset="UTF-8">
<!--input id="date" name="check_in_date" value="" -->
<input class="field-promocode" type="hidden" name="promotion_code" value="">
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div class="procode_select form-item">
            <label>OFFERS</label><br />
            <div class="procode_select_content"><div class="main_select">Special offers</div>
            <div class="main_select_content" style="display: none;">
                
                <div class="procode_option" rel="ebird">
                <div class="main_subselect" rel="2,3">
                <div class="radio_div"></div>Early Bird</div>
                <div class="main_subselect_content" style="display: none;"> Romantic dinner for 2 in the romantic</div>
                </div>
                
                <div class="procode_option" rel="3nrom">
                <div class="main_subselect" rel="5">
                <div class="radio_div"></div>3 nights romance</div>
                <div class="main_subselect_content" style="display: none;">STAY 5 nights / Pay 4 nights. Price includes: 1 x Complimentary night including breakfast. 1 x 1 Hour massage for 2 people. Valid till the 22<sup>th</sup> December 2016</div>
                </div>
                
                <div class="procode_option" rel="1BedroomVilla">
                <div class="main_subselect" rel="3">
                <div class="radio_div"></div>Another Option</div>
                <div class="main_subselect_content" style="display: none;">Get 1x One hour spa for two<br>+ 1x dining for two</div>
                </div>
                
                <div class="procode_option" rel="1BedroomVilla">
                <div class="main_subselect" rel="2">
                <div class="radio_div"></div>STAY 2 NIGHTS</div>
                <div class="main_subselect_content" style="display: none;">Stay 6 Pay 5 </div>
                </div>
                
                <div class="procode_option" rel="111ph">
                <div class="main_subselect" rel="3">
                <div class="radio_div"></div>One Another option</div>
                <div class="main_subselect_content" style="display: none;">An exclusive 3 bedroom villa set above One Eleven’s private sanctuary. The Penthouse is contemporary in design, with an uber chic lounge area, generous dining space and a kitchen with full cooking facilities</div>
                </div>
                
            </div></div>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
<div class="book_direct" style="text-align:left;">Book Direct for<br/><a   style="padding:0; text-align:left;" href="#">best rate guarantee</a></div>
            <input type="submit" id="edit-submit-password" name="op" value="Book Now" class="form-submit">
            </div>
            </form>
```

Comment: Where's the code you are working with?

Comment: Post the JavaScript code you've tried.

Comment: Man, I tried to write it for you but I surrendered. Your HTML code is so messy that I got headache trying to correct the formatting. Tidy it up, then ask.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jQuery UI Accordion. [Read here](https://jqueryui.com/accordion/)

This is what your are looking for.

Comment: It's not necessary. He can do this using jQuery. `.slideToggle()` will do the job.

Comment: I know that but the design posted in the image fits the accordion. Safes him more time @SebastianKaczmarek